# mint mate 20.2 network stops working after restart since change

Tags: linux, wifi, dns, lan

my system stopped working right, maybe last patch maybe i did something wrong. please look into it,and maybe somebody has a solution,what or how i can change it to get it working again
the main isuse is, since today,the one and only w10 client, cant get a dns solution anymore, meaning, pings thru the whole network,work well, but giving it a outside ip, like 8.8.8.8 it fails

base, i will list ips but for the sake of it,only the last .part ,

router 192.168.2.1
pc1 lan .2 (mint mate 20.2)
pc1 wlan .15
pc2 lan .3 (windows 10, routing thru pc1,then router)

and several phones tablets etc..no matter for that issue

the situation was, pc2 runs thru pc 1 via routing the works for years, many years.. 20 maybe? of course parts changed often.
i had one change a couple days ago, the lan route was via a power 1200 mbit network thingi, well it was to slow for our new dsl 1gbit. so i changed it, since pc2 is next to the router, she just calls my pc thru the router,and connects from there.
in short, i simply routed the lan .2 to my wlan .15 instead the router. (40% more speed via speedtest.net,simply because wlan 5g instead of powernetwork)
it worked well for 2 days, then i did restart this morning. kinda a misstake.
it stopped working and she doesnt get any dns solution
-network pings ,all work well,every single one
pinging external from pc2, fails badly (like ping 8.8.8.8, ping google.com) stuff
checking if pc2 con,works directly to the router.. yes without a issue

why do i have to make that loop thru pc1, simply because my asus router,worked will for 250mbit vpn,but cannot handle 1gbit, i let that my linux mainpc handle, and my wifes pc,has to run thru my pc, to get a vpn con to the web.

it did work for 2 days, i simply did change the ip from the lan to the wlan,and from there to router to web (the router does not use vpn functions anymore,and does not limit speed that way)

so iam up for solutions and tests, i simply lack the linux knowledge why my working system did stop just from a restart, the dns lines 8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4 are still in both connections.
i can connection just fine, even to my wifes m.2s

thanks for your time,cant wait to get a working solution instead of digging thru router + linux networking without a idea whats lacking

Comment: Please consider revising the text. Your question is fairly complete, and you give plenty of information - which is great - but the lack of punctuation or capitalization makes it confusing to read.